# Two Inequalities regarding Expectation

Tags: statistics, inequality, probability-distributions, expected-value

I was asked the following questions by my professor. Suppose $X$ is a random variable, which of the following is correct or all incorrect:
\begin{align}
a . E[e^X] \geq E[1+X+X^2/2!]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
b . E[X^2 + 1/X^2 + e^{3X}] \geq E[3e^X]
\end{align}

The first inequality looks having something to do with Taylor expansion. However I don't think $X$ is always positive so the first one is probability violated. For the second one, my initial thought was to bound $x^2+1/x^2$ which is 1 but not sure if we take expectation, how does that translate.

Comment: Presumably, they should all be $X$ or $x.$

Comment: If the question is asking "does this inequality hold for all random variables $X$?" then I think it suffices to consider the the non-random case where $X$ is some real number with probability $1$, i.e. for (b) check whether $x^2 + 1/x^2 + e^{3x} \ge 3e^x$ holds for all real $x$.

Comment: It may help to note that $x^2 + 1/x^2 \geq 2$ always (assuming we avoid the undefined case of $x=0$).

Answer (score 1):

To see that the first inequality can be violated, consider the constant random variable $X=-1$.

For the second, consider the function $f(x)=x^2+1/x^2+e^{3x}-3e^x$ for $x\ne 0$. As Michael points out, $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for $x \ne 0$, where $g(x)=2 + e^{3x}-3e^x$. In turn, one can show that $g'(x)=3e^x(e^{2x}-1)$; therefore $g$ is decreasing on $(-\infty, 0)$ and increasing on $(0, \infty)$, taking a minimum value of $0$ at $x=0$. So $g(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.